# Visual studio 2015 not responding while debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

currently using Visual Studio 2015. And at random occasions when I am debugging my code Visual Studio 2015 will get "Not responding" and never start again so I have to restart the application. First I thought it was due my code, but it's not (I think) It doesn't always crash but it does crash 8/10.

And always at random locations sometimes just when I start debugging, and sometimes when I debugged half of the code and sometimes just at the end.

And I am the only one that is facing this issue?

Comment: In my case sometimes, when in debug mode, VS2015 searches online for available extensions related to the project and after a couple of minutes gives the following message with a list of available extensions useful for that project: `Based on your project we identified these extensions that you may find helpful:` VS gives you a choice to not to display that message again. During that time VS hangs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must have been something with my computer.
I did a fresh install and so far I have not had any issues while debugging.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you might need more memory for VS 2015. VS2015 takes more memory comparing to old versions.

Comment: currently rocking 32 gb, and I would assume that would be enough.